# Multiple response from server within a Ajax call in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax, ajax-polling

What will be the possible ways to send multiple responses to the client side within a Ajax call.

**Scenario**

1.Import 200 records from excel through Ajax.

2.Read file record one by one.

3.On each iteration I need to send some data to client side and get it back with some base 64 image on server side and then save that image into the database.

4.Do this for all the iterations.

5.After all iterations show Ajax success message.

How can I achieve this with in one Ajax request.

Comment: Why does point #3 need to go to the client?

Comment: We need client help to make a base 64 image from JS library - Konva. Each record fetch some data from database and send it to client which make an image from it and send it back to the server to save it in database.

Comment: Unless you can replace Konva with something from the server-side, you will have to do multiple AJAX calls.  It cannot be one AJAX request by nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally We did it by [Signal R](http://signalr.net/).

We can achieve this by Web Sockets or Signal R. Signal R opens a communication channel for client side from there we can get any data to the server again.

**Note** Don't forget to increase the size of Signal R message buffer if anyone wants to send a large file through Signal R e.g.

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 200
```